# How to find the last IP used for an expired domain name?

Tags: dns, ip, domain

Is it possible to look up the last IP address of an expired domain name?

Comment: I dont think this is possible.  Once it leaves your cache, and successive DNS caches, you wont be able to resolve it...

Comment: Not sure if that what you want, but there are [services](http://myip.ms/) online which can provide history of IP addresses for domain.

Comment: I would start with a whois search on the domain to find their registry domain id. then use it to search for any publically available registrar records. you may find some services do charge for IP and NS history information, like this one, showing registrar info for purple.com: http://domainreport.domaintools.com/purple.com

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can find that information using the [ViewDNS.info](http://viewdns.info/iphistory/) IP History page. I can see the last 3 IP addresses for a domain I let expire earlier this year and the two IP addresses used in the past for a domain I let expire several years ago (it might have been about 5 years now since it expired). There's no cost to perform a search on a domain name's IP history at the site.

Comment: Doesn't work with preev.com, which is an expired domain.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to find an IP address of an expired domain if you know where the previous DNS server is. For example if you want to know IP address of **domain.com** from DNS server **nsserver.com**, you just type:

`nslookup domain.com nsserver.com`

The result should be like that:

> Server: nsserver.com
>   Address:  1.2.3.4#53
>
> Name: domain.com
>   Address: 4.3.2.1

And thats it.

Comment: This only works if the nameserver at nsserver.com is still hosting the domain.

Comment: It worked with one of my domains after 1 day from the transfer, I managed to recover the IP of the previous server and recover the email history.
Tomáš Lieskovan saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Other useful sources besides viewdns.info:

- https://dnshistory.org/
- 2013 DNS census: https://dnscensus2013.neocities.org/ I've explored that dataset a bit at: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/dataset-of-domain-names/21077#21077
- https://ipinf.ru: very good website. Not the most complete data, but has a decent bit on the 2010-era I was interested in, and it also has the best neighboring IP -> domain list I've ever seen on a free website so far. Also I haven't hit any number of query limits so far unlike viewdns.info which limits you to 200 queries.

The data of these three sources is disjoint, so searching all of them can be fruitful.

Another one is: https://securitytrails.com/dns-trails appears to be the most complete one I've seen so far. I believe without great evidence that they have pieced up other databases together. Signup blacklists common email providers like gmail to force professional accounts. Query limit appears to be 100/day.

Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33395/find-the-ip-address-of-expired-domains